# Should we remove dom out of the view from dom tree when scroll on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, zepto

When our page run on mobile device ,is it a good idea to remove dom from dom tree which out of the view when scroll out and resume them when scroll in ?

I make a zepto plugin to do this job:

[activeScroll.js](https://github.com/csonlai/activeScroll.js)

but i don't know how to measure if it is necessary to do this job.

Comment: Probably not. What is your reasoning behind any of this? Are you having memory issues with long lists of data?

Comment: Maybe on some device,so many dom in dom tree will slow down the page.

Comment: Then what you're probably looking for is a pageable list